# Streaming microphone audio input through network (RAW PCM)

Tags: javascript, html, networking, audio, html5-audio

What's the best way of recording raw pcm audio using only javascript? I'll be streaming it through a networked connection, and then I would need to reassemble the packets on the other side. The networking part is already done, but I can't seem to figure out how to record, and then put the raw pcm packets into a player, which then let's me hear it on the speakers.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Not tested, but this how I would go about it

1. Ask for permission to use the mic
2. Use the callback which has a stream as input and connect it to a ScriptProcessor
3. The ScriptProcessor gives you an array of samples

Here are some code snippets that might help

```
// ask for permission
navigator.getUserMedia( {audio:true}, successCB, errorCB );
```

A callback exemple

```
function successCB(stream) {
    const ctx = new AudioContext();
    const mediaStreamSource = ctx.createMediaStreamSource(stream);

    const scriptNode = ctx.createScriptProcessor(4096, 1, 1);
    scriptNode.onaudioprocess(audioProcessingEvent => {
        const inputBuffer = audioProcessingEvent.inputBuffer;
        const inputData = inputBuffer.getChannelData(0 /*channel*/);

        for (var sample = 0; sample < inputBuffer.length; sample++) {
            const THE_SAMPLE = inputData[sample];
            // save it in an array ?
        }
    });
    
    // connect the mic to the script
    mediaStreamSource.connect(scriptNode);

    // if you need to hear yourself (be careful with feedback or use headphones)
    mediaStreamSource.connect( ctx.destination );
}
```

FYI, the ScriptProcessor has been deprecated for the AudioWorkletNode which I haven't tried yet.

Comment: This is all good, but once I transmitted the data to the other side, how would I play it? So I have a callback there when a new audio packet comes in, and I should put it into a buffer or something. Could you tell me how I could do that?

Comment: Same code but using audioProcessingEvent.outputBuffer to get a pointer to the output buffer then outputData[sample] = YOUR_DATA and connecting the ScriptProcessor to ctx.destination